# Cannot to get twitter data in specific location

Tags: twitter, location, streaming, twitter4j

I try to get American tweets using Twitter4J, when I set the specific location like this code:

```
    FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();        
    double lat1 = 48.996059d;
    double long1 = -125.361695d;
    double lat2 = 29.269125d;
    double long2 = -67.683473d;
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    double[][] bb = {{lat1, long1}, {lat2, long2}};
    fq.locations(bb);
    twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

I got error like this:

> Parameter not accepted with the role. 406:Returned by the Search API when an invalid format is specified in the request.
>   Returned by the Streaming API when one or more of the parameters are not suitable for the resource. The track parameter, for example, would throw this error if:
>    The track keyword is too long or too short.
>    The bounding box specified is invalid.
>    No predicates defined for filtered resource, for example, neither track nor follow parameter defined.
>    Follow userid cannot be read.
>   Latitude/longitude are not valid: 49.00, -125.36, 29.27, -67.68

I guess Twitter4J cannot read minus(-) coordinate, because when I set without minus, it works.

Thank you for any reply

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by self. It must SW first